# How to configure MAMP PRO nginx server for symfony on Mac

Tags: symfony, nginx, configuration, mamp

since I have an Macbook, I use MAMP PRO to run several local servers. Now I want to change from Apache to nginx. But I allways get an 404.

What does a working standard nginx configuration for Symfony 3.x look like?

Thanks, Anton

Answer (score 1):

The following configuration works:

Directory Index: `app.php`
try_files: `$uri /index.php$is_args$args;`
Custom:

```
$uri /index.php$is_args$args;
location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI_php7.1.8.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include          /Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
```

Comment: Also works for Drupal . But I had to remove the `$uri /index.php$is_args$args;` in the custom part

Comment: @wessel I can't make it work for Drupal. Do you have extra conf ? I took the NGINX Drupal Recipe but Nginx does not even start.